# Use different colors for start and end timers of the slider in wijmo.css

Tags: css, wijmo

I am using jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.3.8.min.css.
but i can't find answer......
code:

```
#slider
{
    width: 300px;
}
.wijmo-wijslider-incbutton
{
    /*Sets the styles of the outer edge of the increment button.*/
    background: CornflowerBlue;
}
#slider .ui-slider-handle
{
    /*Sets the styles of the thumb button.*/
    background:#310D4F; 
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: What do you want us to help with?

Comment: how to write code two thumb buttons different colors

Comment: Please show your (relevant/[minimal, complete and verified](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) example HTML so we know what you're working with. Your current CSS doesn't provide sufficient information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background-image as none. Here is the correct css:

```
.wijmo-wijslider-incbutton, .wijmo-wijslider-decbutton {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: red;
    }
```